# rails 5.2 redis cache write data, but redis can't read the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

for test, in controller

```
Rails.cache.write('test', 'aaaa')
```

in reids-cli

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get test
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I set following setting, in config/application.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0' }
```

What went wrong ？

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem. I had a typo in my Redis configuration that instructed my application to connect on the wrong port. I was finally able to diagnose this when I ran `Rails.cache.redis.keys` and got back a `Redis::CannotConnectError`. Not sure why it would be designed to silence connection errors during a cache fetch, but that would make an application more resilient if unable to connect to a cache server.

Also, make sure your cache configuration is in `config/application.rb` or an environment configuration file. It cannot be configured in an initializer.